# Subspace of metric space with finitely many points is complete

Tags: functional-analysis

Show  that:

If a  subspace  $Y$  of  a metric space consists  of finitely many 
points,  then  $Y$  is  complete.

Answer (score 2):

Given any finite subspace $Y$ of a metric space $X$, the Cauchy sequences $(x_n)$ are precisely those sequences which are eventually constant. To see this, observe that $\exists \ N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall \ m,n\geq N$ we have $d(x_m,x_n)<\epsilon$, $\forall \epsilon>0$, but if $x_n\neq x_m$ then the distance won't be zero. Since any Cauchy sequence is eventually constant hence it converges in $Y$ itself,i.e., $Y$ is complete.

Comment: Good answer.  You might consider including the word "discrete" somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Any Cauchy sequence in such a space must be eventually constant.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\left\{ x_{n}\right\} $ be a Cauchy sequence in $Y$. That is, for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N$ s.t. for all $n,m\geq N$, $d\left(x_{n},x_{m}\right)<\epsilon$. Let $\epsilon_{0}$ be the minimum distance between pairs of distinct points in $Y$. $\epsilon_0$ is well-defined since it is a minimum of $\left|Y\right|\left(\left|Y\right|-1\right)$ nonnegative real numbers. From the  hypothesis, there exists an $N_{0}$ s.t. for all $n,m\geq N_{0}$, $d\left(x_{n},x_{m}\right)<\epsilon_{0}$. But, this only occurs if the sequence is constant for all $n\geq N_{0}$!

(hence, every Cauchy sequence converges to some point in the space, and the space is complete)

Comment: You write epsillon is well defined can you clear your reason

Comment: @user150273: Compute the distance between each pair of points. This gives you finitely many distances, since there are only finitely many points (and hence finitely many pairs). Of these distances, pick the smallest one and call it $\epsilon_0$.